# Google ad for publishers, overlay status: not displayed error

Tags: javascript, google-ads-api

Can you spot any issues with this page? There are meant to be skyscraper and leader banners throughout this article, but for some reason it's not displaying.

Any quick spots that I may have missed?

https://universitybusiness.co.uk/people-policy-politics/office-for-students-announces-details-of-nss-review/

Below is the Google Console report for the first ad slot:

[image]

When I test this query in the delivery tools, it just continually runs a loading gif.

Comment: You have give sample input you tried to put ads

Comment: Sorry aviboy2006, could you expand on your explanation?